# Can we specify multiple queries in Firebase?

Tags: sql, database, firebase

```
{
  "lambeosaurus": {
    "height" : 2.1,
    "length" : 12.5,
    "weight": 5000
  },
  "stegosaurus": {
    "height" : 4,
    "length" : 9,
    "weight" : 2500
  }
  "pegosaurus": {
    "height" : 4,
    "length" : 9,
    "weight" : 1000
  }
}
```

I have to apply a query on this structure of dinasaurs whose height=4 and length =9. How can i apply multiple query on firebase?(using orderByChild)